# Can't get infoWindow to show in CartoDB dynamic layer

Tags: javascript, carto, maps, cartocss, infowindow

Here's my very simple code.

```
<title>Leaflet multilayer example | CartoDB.js</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
<div class="cartodb-popup">
<a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
 <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
   <div class="cartodb-popup-header">
     <img style="width: 100%" src="http://cartodb.com/assets/logos/logos_full_cartodb_light-5ef5e4ff558f4f8d178ab2c8faa231c1.png"></src>
   </div>
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
     <!-- content.data contains the field info -->
     <h4>City: </h4>
     <p></p>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
</script>
<!-- include cartodb.js library -->
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
<script>
  function main() {
    // create leaflet map
    var map = L.map('map', { 
      zoomControl: false,
      center: [43, 0],
      zoom: 3
    })

    // add a base layer
    L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Stamen'
    }).addTo(map);

    // add cartodb layer with one sublayer
    cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: 'examples',
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [{
         sql: 'select * from country_boundaries',
         cartocss: '#layer { polygon-fill: #F00; polygon-opacity: 0.3; line-color: #F00; }',
         interactivity: 'cartodb_id'
      }]
    })
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layer) {

      var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
      sublayer.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
    });

  }

  //  $(window).load(main);
  window.onload = main; 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing is showing on click,
here is the github [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77fd50459ecdd961119e)
and the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEBdea) can anyone see where problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/unable-to-make-infowindow-work-in-cartodb-runtime-layer), [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91580/9847) and [this bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/xavijam/9269220).

at least one issue is that you haven't defined #infowindow_template, but you can get a simple onclick popup of the country name by adding the following:

```
cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, layer.getSubLayer(0), ['name']);
```

in place of:

```
sublayer.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
```

It looks like an infowindow template should be possible as the fourth argument to that `addInfowindow()` function, but I wasn't able to get it to work. You will at least need to define it somewhere in your code, as shown in the above linked examples, and also [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/custom_interactivity.html):

```
<script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
  <div class="cartodb-popup">
    <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
     <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
       <div class="cartodb-popup-header">
         <img style="width: 100%" src="http://cartodb.com/assets/logos/logos_full_cartodb_light-5ef5e4ff558f4f8d178ab2c8faa231c1.png"></src>
       </div>
        <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
         <!-- content.data contains the field info -->
         <h4>City: </h4>
         <p></p>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Why do i need to change to that? I have just done it like the documentation says? if i do it your way i will not be able to put custom mark up in the infowindow

Comment: can you give me a link to the documentation so I have a better idea what you're trying to do?